# Access style of a control a modify

Tags: c#, windows-8, bing-maps, windows-8.1

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PushPinStyle" TargetType="Maps:Pushpin">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="HERE MUST BE TEXT" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="ms-appx:///Images/Icons/Pushpin.png" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

When i create pushpin:

```
Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
pushpin.Style = this.Resources["PushPinStyle"] as Style;
```

I want to access the text block's text and visibility properties from C# code.

There will be something like a button "Go to next pushpin" on a page, the map gets centred on other pushpin, and TextBlock is becoming visible

Comment: You should bind properties to textbox's text & visibility. So you can access in code-behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xyroid's comment helped me out:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility}" Text="{Binding Path=Label}" Grid.Row="0"/>
<Image Grid.Row="1" Source="ms-appx:///Images/Icons/Pushpin.png" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```